# How to run a Gulp task with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I want to run the default Gulp task with VS code by using the inbuilt feature to do so. My tasks.json is as follows:

`{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "gulp",
            "task": "default",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}`

When I run the task with the keyboard shortcut(my keybindings are already modified to run the task), I get an options menu with all the list of the Gulp tasks. To actually run the `gulp` command, I have to select the 'gulp:default' task from the list. How can I run the task without having to see the list and selecting the 'gulp:default' option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **.vscode/tasks.json** in the workSpaceRoot:

Try the following - the main thing you need is a "label" to use as an argument in your keybinding - the label can be whatever you want:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Your task label",
            "command": "gulp",
            "args": ["default"],
            "type": "shell",
             "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Keybinding**:

```
    { "key": "shift+escape",  
      "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask", 
      "args": "Your task label here"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

press ctlr+shift+B to run the task

**tasks.json**

`{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "gulp",
            "taskName": "gulp",
            "command": "gulp",
            "args": [
                "html",
                "css"
            ],
            "isShellCommand": true,
            "isBuildCommand": true
        }
    ]
}`

this will run `gulp css` and `gulp html`

Comment: This is how tasks worked in 'legacy' VSCode versions. These properties are not supported now and don't work.

Comment: The version number is  "2.0.0". Are you saying that is legacy version of vsc?

Comment: Look at [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-v1). This is how tasks were written earlier (VSCode <1.13.1). The version no. "2.0.0" is for the tasks version, not VSCode's version. [This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) is the latest docs for tasks.

Comment: well press ctrl+shift+B on vsc and you can create a tasks.json. You will see the version number is 2.0.0