# Shortcut for running terminal command in VS code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make a hotkey for running specific command in terminal? Say I want to compile my TypeScript files by hotkey and not to type to terminal "tsc" or any other variation of that command. (Edit: I know it is possible to recompile TS on save, but the question is still the same)

Comment: if you use a tool like webpack, your typescript file will be recompiled anytime you save

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Typically you would set up a build or another task or an npm script and then trigger that with a hotkey.

There is another new way to do it with [send text to the terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_define-keybindings-to-send-custom-sequences).

For example, try this in your keybindings (*Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)*):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+u",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "node -v\u000D"
  }
}
```

for an npm script:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+u",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "npm run-script test\u000D"
  }
}
```

The first will run the `node -v` command (the `\u000D` is a return so it runs).  I still recommend actually setting up a build task though, and then there are keychords for running your build task:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>.  Or an npm script.

For example, if you had a more complex script to run, see [how to bind a task to a keybinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047352/how-to-run-a-gulp-task-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/49052714#49052714) or [how to keybind an external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725243/vscode-how-to-keybind-an-external-command/50749571#50749571).

---

**EDIT**: As of v1.32 you can now do something like this:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "tsc '${file}'\u000D" }
}
```

You can now use the built-in variables, like `${file}`, with the `sendSequence` command in a keybinding.  I wrapped `${file}` in single quotes in case your directory structure has a folder with a space in the name.  And `\u000D` is a return.

Comment: Only downside to this is the keyboard shortcut fails silently if no terminal is open yet.

Comment: is it possible to run sequence of commands via single shortcut? e.g. "open new terminal" && "run command"

Comment: @godblessstrawberry With a macro extension yes.  See multi-command extension.

Comment: @godblessstrawberry it is possible to run multiple commands. see my answer below. i did not try your exact sequence but should be doable.

Comment: If you want to kill the currently running command, prefix the sequence with `\u0003\n`. This sends a Ctrl-C to the terminal.

Answer (score 25):

You can accomplish this with VSCode `tasks` and then wire up your task to a keybinding. The downside to this approach is you have to have a `tasks.json` file in your workspace `.vscode` folder (it can't be global).

Here is an example where I wanted to open a file in a custom GitHub remote:

```json
// tasks.json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
      {
          "label": "Open in remote",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "open https://github.custom.com/org/repo/blob/master/${relativeFile}#L${lineNumber}"
      }
  ]
}
```

```json
// keybindings.json
{
  "key": "ctrl+o",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "Open in remote"
},
```

Here are some more VS Code variables you can use if you are curious: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

There is a long standing issue open here which should make this easier to do without tasks: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/871

Comment: see also assign task to prelaunchtask in launch configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836861/how-to-run-a-command-in-vs-code-with-launch-json

Answer (score 5):

I don't think vscode by default can do this, but you can try this extension. That work for me.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-script-commands

Answer (score 3):

As a variation on the accepted answer, note that it is also possible to set up hot-keys that run multiple commands via [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands). Below is one that saves the current document, and moves the cursor, prior to invoking a script that operates on it. Open `keybindings.json` using "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" and you could for example insert:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+enter",
        "command": "runCommands",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "workbench.action.files.save",
                "cursorBottom",
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                    "args": {
                        "text": "py -3 myscript.py ${file}\u000D"
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        "when": "editorLangId == markdown"
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to @mark ..

`"args": { "text": "npm run-script test | tee /dev/null \u000D" }`

this way it will run any script including bash scripts, that doesn't conflict to their arguments 
(e.g try rsync without the tee)

Answer (score 1):

You can create one new terminal, then run any command by `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` and don't forget close this new temp terminal by sending `exit\u000D`.

below is the config to add into your keybindings (Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)):

```json
{
        "key": "ctrl+alt+p",
        "command": "runCommands",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                {
                    "command": "openInIntegratedTerminal",
                },
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                    "args": {
                        "text": "npm run build\u000Dexit\u000D"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: superb :)))))))