# Is there any way to add a keyboard shortcut for each script inside built-in NPM Script Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

NPM Script Explorer is convenient for running npm script in a mouse click without navigating to the specific folder and typing the command.

Is there any way can binding specific script such as `build` with keyboard  (`ctrl+R` or setup the hotkey) ?

[NPM Script Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzgVR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search in the keyboard shortcuts for "npm-script" you will see one command for running the npm script `test` already bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>.

There is a command for a "build" script, but it isn't bound to anything yet:

```
npm-script.build
```

You could select that one in the keyboard shortcuts page and set a keybinding to it.

Also see my answer at [shortcut for an npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786022/shortcut-for-running-terminal-command-in-vs-code/52786528#52786528).  For example:

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+u",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "npm run-script someScriptNameHere\u000D"
    }
 }
```

Just replace `someScriptName` with whatever script you want to run, and choose your own keybinding.

Comment: It seems an alternative way to do the shortcut without NPM Script Explorer, this method also solved my problem. thanks !!