# Is there a keybind to quickly run C# in VSCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to learn C#, and found the standard `Ctrl+Alt+N` does not work, and the tutorials online regarding building C# projects all seem to only mention using the command line with `dotnet run`. I have no problem with the command line, but it would greatly help my workflow if I didn't have to switch to mouse or trackpad to click the terminal and then back again.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786022/shortcut-for-running-terminal-command-in-vs-code/52786528#52786528 using `sendSequence`

Answer (score 5):

From the VS Code extensions Marketplace download and install the "**terminal-command-keys**" (by Pete Kinnecom) extension.

Open "**keybindings.json**" file (View > Command Palette > search for: " >preferences:Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"

In "keybindings.json" file put the following code **inside the brackets** "[]" :

```
{
    "key": "cmd+3",
    "command":"terminalCommandKeys.run",
    "args":{
        "cmd": "dotnet run"
    }

}
```

**Save** your "keybindings.json" file. (I have assigned "cmd + 3" key combination to "dotnet run" command. Use your own favorite key combination!

Notes:

1. There is **no space** between cmd and + and 3 in the code.
2. Pay attention to **letter case** of "terminalCommandKeys.run".
3. Just to be sure, **restart** VS Code.

Source: [Medium: Francis Mendez](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-assign-terminal-commands-onto-keybindings-in-vs-code-streamlining-your-debugging-process-a42a027c38d3)

Comment: This worked for me with a slight variation. I needed to run out of the folder of the active file, so i used `"cmd": "cd $(dirname \"${file}\") && dotnet run"`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about VSCode, but in normal VS build is Shift+Ctrl+B

Comment: He asked about dotnet run though?

Comment: Ahh, then don't try my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can install an extension to help you with that. Here is some information: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1373/debugging-aspnet-core-using-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

Not a shortcut, but one can conveniently run the csproj in watch mode.

```
dotnet watch --project <project file name>.csproj
```