# Run Powershell script from anywhere in VScode (basically hotkey a .ps1 script)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I write text files in markdown format, in Visual Studio Code. I have a powershell script (.ps1) that I use to convert a markdown file (.md) to a pdf file.

Currently, I have to go to the .ps1 file to execute every time I want to generate the pdf-file. I would like to run the .ps1 file without leaving the markdown file, preferably with a hotkey (f5?). Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52786528/836330

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring a [custom VS code keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

1. Open keybindings.json document. To do this, use `ctrl+shift+p` and then select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.
2. Create an entry to run your script (see example below).

---

This example will run the Powershell script `C:\Users\paolo\hello-world.ps1` when `f5` is pressed:

```
{
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "powershell C:\\Users\\paolo\\hello-world.ps1\u000D" }
}
```

although do note that `f5` is already configured to run debugging, so I wouldn't use that.