# In VS code how to automate a key press of keyboard for any command on terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-tasks

After running a task which runs "npx react-native start" on terminal

Then i see metro logo with instruction and I have to press "a" key for android. So rather pressing key manually how can we automate it?

I tried passing args in task inside task.json and also tried
echo "a" | npx react-native start but it did not help. We can't run
'npx react-native start a' we have to wait and press 'a' key.
Ref : metro after running 'npx react-native start'.
[image]

I tried this task in vscode but it simply executes "npx react-native start a"

```
"command": "npx react-native start", // or npx react native start
"args": ["a"],
// also tried using ${input:keyA}
```

also tried sendSequence

```
   {
        "key": "ctrl+numpad5",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
            "text": "npm start"
        }
        // I dont know how exactly i should use this.
        // "terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
        //    "a - run on Android": "a\r"
        // },
    }
```

Extra ref: [React Native's metro script which takes input](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a9dd43c5c61c6147c6a8caaa01fb1729c4d7e8d2/packages/community-cli-plugin/src/commands/start/attachKeyHandlers.js)
in this file you can see how it seeking for user input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcut for running terminal command in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786022/shortcut-for-running-terminal-command-in-vs-code)

Comment: No this does not answer my question.

Comment: ... you edited, but didn't say what happens when you use `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence`.

Comment: tried workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence as well. I am exploring various answers and sites. But could find anything wokring.  in doc of vscode they says we can send  keys like enter, arrow, enter etc.  But it does not work or i could not use maybe.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have my bash code and have the same problem :(

Comment: I reached to the code which is responsible for showing the metro logo and command instructions below logo. I have to learn about node input output working to talk further about it. So for now I left it but will start working on it later and provide answer if I got success