How can I create a configuration to update dependencies?
I have the statusbar_commands extension installed
How can I create a button to update my dependencies in my code
I tried the following code
{
"statusbar_command.commands": [
   {
      "text": "$(gear) Update",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": {
        "text": "npm update"
      }
    }
]
}

the button created above does not execute anything in the vscode terminal
What is the right way to do this ?

are you not just missing the newline character? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52786022/11107541

@starball so I use the extension statusbar_commands I've already tried the same methodology as you posted the link and it doesn't work

no, I mean, does "text": "npm update\u000D" not work for you? what exactly are you observing when you say "does not execute anything"?

It doesn't work, I click the button and nothing is executed, even using it the way you mentioned

does any other command work?

None, nothing I enter is executed
